# Selenium does not record my test anylonger?

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

Totally new to selenium but have to teach it to some students. Yesterday I successfully installed selenium ide 2.9.1 in firefox, recorded a simple test where I typed in an url and clicked a few clicks on the website. After that I exported the test to java and created a project in intellij where I can run my test. Today I tried the same thing, first on another computer without sucess, and then same thing on the computer I tried yesterday, also without sucess. The old test is still working, but I cannot record a new test starting by typing the url. Clicks are recorded but not typing. Probably my fault. I've searched for updates but cannot find anything that should have changed either java, firefox or selenium since yesterday. Any advice would be of great help.

Yesterdays test use
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
but todays test use
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

Comment: I'm on 2.9.1 and it's record type commands for me in simple html input elements. What's the underlying html of the places your typing look like? Sometimes javascript can cause these fields to be not recorded.